# Run a celery worker on Django with % replacements

Tags: python, django, celery

Is there a way to run celery with django's manage.py without it ignoring % replacements such as:

```
python manage.py celery worker -c3 --logfile=%n-%i.log
```

Currently this just produces a log file with the name `%n-%i.log`

Comment: Did you try using quotes (as in `--logfile="%n-%i.log"`)?

Comment: Yep, tried that. It's a no go :(

Comment: I can't find any reference that Celery expands %n in the logfile, or %i anywhere. Where did you see that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - It is documented in the [Workers Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#variables-in-file-paths).